# Activity with no Title/Action bar

Tags: android, android-activity, android-titlebar

First off, I'm not completely sure that Title Bar and Action Bar are the same? 2 different things?

I have an existing application that I need to maintain. In I have an activity that had a custom view as a title. What I want is to have the default title bar for the activity - the native one. I removed the custom view, and in the activity class I removed `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` but the activity still doesn't show the Title bar. I've set the activity theme to `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"`. Still no Title Bar.

The activity intent is started with `launchActivityForResult` - don't know if that has anything to do with that.

What am I missing here? Is there a way to show it programmatically?

Comment: You can use toolbar in the activity to show as Title bar

Answer (score 0):

1. title-bar and action-bar is different thing.
2. use theme like this.

> ```
> Theme.AppCompat.Light 
>
> instead of
>
> Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
>
>    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
>         <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
>         <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
>         <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
>     </style>
> ```

and add this theme to manifest

```
 <application
        android:name="com.qwesys.ecommerce.application.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
```

Answer (score 0):

*First off, I'm not completely sure that Title Bar and Action Bar are the same? 2 different things?*

Yes these are 2 different things implementation wise. Action Bar is now deprecated and we use something called the toolbar.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

You can make customized toolbar https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html

And for your second part use startActivityForResult() and like suggested by @sagar above you use the theme to to make the toolbar appear.